# sending multiple base64 images to cloudinary using node and getting error -4064, code: 'ENAMETOOLONG'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, base64, redux-toolkit, cloudinary

I am getting my base64 urls and they are correct because if I send only one image its uploaded correctly to cloudinary but when sending multiple images Ii get an error 'ENAMETOOLONG' with error number 4064

here is my graphql resolver

```
createEvent: async (args: any, req: any) => {
    if (!req.isAuth) {
      throw new Error("Unauthenticated!!!!");
    }
    let imagesArr: any[] = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < args.eventInput.images.length; i++) {
      const result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(
        args.eventInput.images[i],
        {
          public_id: `${args.eventInput.title}${new Date(
            args.eventInput.date
          )}${i}`,
          folder: "Eventers",
          allowedFormats: ["jpeg", "png", "jpg"],
        }
      );
      console.log(result.url, result.public_id);
      imagesArr.push({ public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url });
    }

    const event = new Event({
      title: args.eventInput.title,
      description: args.eventInput.description,
      price: +args.eventInput.price,
      date: new Date(args.eventInput.date),
      category: args.eventInput.category,
      brief: args.eventInput.brief,
      tickets: +args.eventInput.tickets,
      images: [...imagesArr],
      author: req.userId,
    });
    let createdEvent;
    try {
      const result = await event.save();
      createdEvent = transformEvent(result);
      const author = await User.findById(req.userId);

      if (!author) {
        throw new Error("User not found.");
      }
      author.createdEvents.push(event);
      await author.save();

      return createdEvent;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      throw error;
    }
  },
```

here is the response i get when trying to submit multiple base64 urls

```
message: "Unexpected error value: { error: { errno: -4064, code: \"ENAMETOOLONG\", syscall: \"open\", path: \"C:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\Desktop\\\\graphQl maximillian yt course\\\\bookingEvents\\\\backend\\\\data:image\\\\jpeg;base64,\\\\9j\\\\4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD\\\\2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj\\\\2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj\\\\wAARCAQIAkUDASIAAhEBAxEB\\\\8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\\\\8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6\\\\8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL\\\\8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uP…"
```

and here is how i transform the images to base

```
const fileOnChangeHandler = async (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let files = Array.from(e.target.files!);
    files.forEach((file: any) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onloadend = async () => {
        setImageLinks((prevArr: any) => [...prevArr, reader.result]);
      };
    });
  };
```

and here is how i send the data to the back end

```
export const fetchAsyncCreateEvents = createAsyncThunk(
  "Events/fetchAsyncCreateEvents",
  async (eventInput: Event) => {
    const {
      title,
      category,
      description,
      brief,
      price,
      date,
      tickets,
      images,
    } = eventInput;
    const { data } = await axios.post<Event>(
      API,
      {
        query: `
                  mutation{
                    createEvent(eventInput:{title:"${title}",category:"${category}",description:"""${description}""",brief:"${brief}",price:${price},date:"${date}",tickets:${tickets},images:"${images}"}){
                    
                      author{
                            email
                         }
                      }
                  }
              `,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }
    );
    return data;
  }
);
```

I've tried alot of things like adding .replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"") to the for loop at each image array index but it didnt work

and here is one of the base 64 urls

```
 "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
```

I deleted more than half of the url so I could submit the question.

Comment: The `ENAMETOOLONG` error message is a bit vague, since the individual uploads are working and you are uploading individually within the for loop, it seems like something would be wrong with the data transformation happening within the for loop. Are you able to console log the data at each step and assure that it's as expected? 

Having the final base64 would help to determine if there's any additions happening causing the error as well.

Comment: thank you i found the problem but i didnt solve it . it appears that the data transformation is transforming the first file correctly but the others isnt right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved the problem it was so simple the problem is i am sending the array of images base64 in a wrong way in graphql mutation
i was sending it with a quotation wrapping it and it turned out you have to use quotations only for strings and for arrays you should json.stringify

```
export const fetchAsyncCreateEvents = createAsyncThunk(
  "Events/fetchAsyncCreateEvents",
  async (eventInput: Event) => {
    const {
      title,
      category,
      description,
      brief,
      price,
      date,
      tickets,
      images,
    } = eventInput;
    const { data } = await axios.post<Event>(
      API,
      {
        query: `
                  mutation{
                    createEvent(eventInput:{title:"${title}",category:"${category}",description:"""${description}""",brief:"${brief}",price:${price},date:"${date}",tickets:${tickets},images:${JSON.stringify(images)}}){
                    
                      author{
                            email
                         }
                      }
                  }
              `,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
        },
      }
    );
    return data;
  }
);
```